# Puppet Open Source connect to PuppetDB or DB?

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I installed Puppet Open Source and I want to read the DB how can I do that and what should I do for it?

I found this git repo:
[the PuppetDB GitHub repo](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetdb) but I cant start anything with it.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow the docs [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppetdb/5.1/index.html) to install PuppetDB.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Alex Harvey, I have for github repo from that link which you send, but there not to much Informations to start with.... did you do that before ?

Comment: I haven’t done it for a while but the installation instructions in the doc I linked look pretty easy to follow. You don’t need the GitHub repo.

Comment: okay thank you so much :-), Ill follow the link which you send and I hope it will work :-), thanks again Alex :-)